# Pandas Pivot table : Get only the value counts and not columns

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table with a data set with many columns.
When making a pivot table with code below I get all the columns which I don't want.

I only want the counts and not any other columns there. Can i achieve this ?

```
table1 = pd.pivot_table(dfCALCNoExcecption,index=['AD Platform','Agent Program'],columns=None,aggfunc='count')
```

The output of above code in excel output is like below( I have not pasted the whole as there are around 50 columns):
[image: Sample Output with many more columns hidden]

The Desired Output I am trying to get:

[image: Desired Output with only counts of machine, without any other columns]

Comment: better with `groupby`: `df.groupby('AD Platform')['Agent Program'].value_counts()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang , Thanks, this works, it's sorted by Value Counts, can that be sorted by Agent Version ?

Comment: I think it can be `.value_counts(sorted=False)` Or you can chain that with `sort_index`.

Comment: @QuangHoang ,  I am finding to sort by Agent Versions. I tried this , No keyword as 'sorted' : TypeError: value_counts() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sorted'

Answer (score 2):

You can group by your data based on the columns 'AD Plataform' and 'Agent Program'. After that, you can sum all the values of the column that has the quantity of the machines. Here is my code:

df.groupby(['AD Plataform', 'Agent Program'])['AD Hostname'].sum()

Comment: df.groupby(['AD Platform', 'Agent Program'])['AD Hostname'].count()    works. I am trying to sort this by agent Versions. Thanks this worked changing .sum() to count()

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete but a part of this can be achieved by Groupby. I am not sure how to rename the third column to "Count"

```
dfAgentTable3 =  dfCALCNoExcecption.groupby(['AD Platform', 'Agent Program'])['AD Hostname'].count().sort_index(ascending=True)
```

[image]